# What is the word for a meaning

Tags: word-usage, word-request, word-meaning

I'd like to know the exact word in English for the agricultural machine for digging and cleaning ditches (to facilitate the flow of water). I think *bulldozer* is not the right one for this.

Comment: You dig a ditch by hand or with an earth moving machine: an excavator.

Comment: Can you give us a picture of one? There's many machines for digging and cleaning ditches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would probably use one of these to dig or maintain a ditch. In Britain, we might call such a machine more formally, a mechanical excavator or mechanical digger, or less formally, just a 'digger'. The first well known British digger was made in the 1950s by a company called JCB, and many British people still call a digger of any make a 'JCB'. I believe Americans would call one of these machines a 'backhoe'.

[image]

Comment: Concur, "excavator" or "backhoe" are the American terms.

Comment: @randomhead, you may post it as an answer